# How do I pronounce the name "Aurelius"?

Tags: pronunciation, names

I was reading a book out-loud and came across this name. At the time, I pronounced it

> Aurelius: ur-ell-ee-us

The more I think about it, the more I'm sure it is not correct. The word `Aura` would seem to make it pronounced `or-ell-ee-us`, and the name `Auriel` I have always read as `are-ee-ell` *which could also be incorrect*.

What is the correct pronunciation of `Aurelius` and `Auriel`?

*Additionally, some information on the background would make an even better answer*.

---

off-topic: I don't remember the title of the book but it was about Merlin.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the pronunciation of a ***proper noun/name***, not a normal English word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Um, so? It’s an English word.

Comment: @tchrist: You're a native speaker, so if you think it's an English word there's no point in me trying to convince you otherwise. But it doesn't ***mean*** anything to me. Apart from the name of an [ancient Roman emperor](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/364331/Marcus-Aurelius), that is. The idea that there's a "correct" pronunciation in such cases seems a bit daft to me. At least with something like ***Linux*** you might make a case for saying the correct pronunciation is whatever is endorsed by the person thus named, but here I think it's just a straw poll.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's a borrowing _in_ English, so it's perfectly on topic to discuss. It is however off-topic because it is gen ref as is.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm hopeless at IPA (ever other chart I find seems different in the details, and I get confused when things seem to turn on US/UK differences in enunciating "the same" sound). But if this is GR to you, I must admit I'm none the wiser after seeing two answers here, plus an IPA transciption in [*The McGraw-Hill Encyclopedia of World Biography*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Spanish+Marcus+Aurelius+pronounced%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). All we seem to have achieved here is the loss of a potentially valuable user.

Comment: Of course this question isn't "off-topic." English speakers generally apply different rules to the pronunciation of Latin names than the Romans used themselves; the details are absolutely appropriate for this site. And I just looked up "Aurelius" in three different online references and found no pronunciation advice, so it's not "general reference" either.

Comment: @phenry gen ref: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/marcus+aurelius. But wth I'll vote to reopen anyway.

Comment: Reading your question, you seem to wonder about the first vowel sound, but it's the second vowel that got me... it seems you consistently pronounce that with a short vowel, whereas I don;t think I've ever heard it with anything but a long [i:].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site, *[howjsay.com](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=aurelius)* gives  the pronunciation of *Aurelius* as most speakers of Southern British English pronounce it.

Aurelius: awe + **rea**lly + ous (as in famous)

IPA: /ɔː'riːliəs/

Comment: While I'm not quibbling about this way of pronouncing _Aurelius_, I'd love to know how 'standard English' is defined (I assume there aren't conflicting definitions?). You need to show attributions on this side of any links.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand "You need to show attributions on this side of any links".  I have reworded my 'standard English', which was not very helpful.

Comment: Hotlink, mentioning the source in your text.

Comment: This tells us nothing. It is not an answer. You must answer the question within your own posting.

Comment: @tchrist - When I have answered a question myself  in other threads, I have been  told I must provide a reference or my post will be disregarded as just my own opinion. Here I provided a source and   I am told I must answer the question myself. It sometimes seems that this site is more interested in the way questions are answered than in ensuring that people who have asked questions receive helpful information.

Comment: Your post will be helpful once I can listen to audio - which is why I up-voted. I think the goal is that references are encouraged in order to back up the answer in your post, but you don't want to use them to directly provide the answer. If the link died, your answer is no longer helpful to others.

Comment: @tunny This site is concerned with providing information which is complete and self-contained. That means that **link-only answers like this one are bad** as they are prone to link-rot; and uncorroborated opinion is just that — opinion, and no *more* worthy of consideration than anyone else's opinion.

Comment: @ tunny: I hope you'll reconsider. The quality of some of your other answers imply you're probably quite capable of orthographically reproducing the salient detail in IPA (and you could obviously do it in "eye-dialect"). I doubt tchrist intended his comment to be overly hostile - he just likes to be exceptionally concise sometimes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yup: ðə ˈseɪliənt/ˈseɪljənt ˈdi:teɪl. I'm not really concerned about other people's reactions to my posts. However, I have no wish to cause  problems anywhere and, aware that conforming is not high on my list of priorities, I'll take my maverick tendencies elsewhere. It's been fun, but it's better to quit before it ceases to be fun.

Comment: I'll miss you, but obviously you can't be held against your will, and there's no point being here if you don't enjoy it. Whatever - best of luck if you go looking for a "similar but better" site, and if this does turn out to be your last post, let [this pointer to an answer of yours which imho is beyond reproach](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/204775/2637) stand as a pointer to what could have been a mutually beneficial state of affairs.

Comment: (btw - I'm one of several "awkward non-conformists" who manage to put up with the flack. It's *possible*, even if you could do without it.)

Comment: Thanks. Before I depart, I must make one thing very clear: I am not looking for a 'better' site. I may be looking for one that is more tolerant of my foibles but I have no complaints at all about the quality of this site. It's first class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18444/discussion-between-tunny-and-fumblefingers).

Comment: You say you want to provide helpful answers, and you do. I thought this one was quite good. It takes time to become familiar with a community, and for it to become familiar with you. I want to invite you to hang in there; I think it's a good place.

Comment: My apologies in advance for posting this in the wrong place, but I am unable to continue the discussion in chat. In the place where I think I should be able to start what I want to write is a note telling me I need 20 reputations before I can post.  Could somebody please tell me how I can carry on there?

Comment: I am now able to continue this discussion in chat.

Answer (score 3):

I think there might be slightly different versions of correct pronunciation, but here is one I know:

> /ɔːˈriːliəs/

Answer (score 0):

I named my daughter Auriella a varient of Auriela and a female version of Aurelius and i pronounce it as
Au (aw like cow)
Ri (ree as in REEd)
ella (Ella)

The name means golden as far as i am aware.

So i would pronounce Aurelius as
Au (aw)
re (Re)
Li (lee)
Us (uss)